# How do I find out the MAC address of my iPad?

Tags: ipad, network

I have a new iPad and MAC address filtering on my home wifi network. How do I figure out the MAC address of my iPad?

Comment: @Moshe, I did go through all my questions and accepted all of them. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On my iPhone, I can find my MAC address by going into Settings, then General, then About. The wifi MAC address is listed under "Wi-Fi Address". It's likely that the MAC address for the iPad is in the same location.

Comment: The bluetooth MAC is here as well if you ever need it.

Comment: Kyle is correct. The iPad MAC addresses (for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth) are in Settings->General->About

Answer (score 1):

As a slight aside, [iNet Pro](http://www.bananaglue.de/inet/index_e.php) will show you the MAC address (and a lot more) of all devices on the network your iPhone is connected to.

Answer (score 1):

The free app [*IPView*](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ipview/id374164454?mt=8) shows:

- cellular IP
- Public IP
- Wifi IP
- Wifi MAC

addresses.
The UI is less than stunning, but it works fine.